# How to solve sorting numbers issue using directives in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have sort Directive in my Angular 8. For sorting string values it works fine but in case of numbers it is not working.

My Sort Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sortColumn]'
})
export class SortDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any;
  @Input('sortKey') key: any;
  @Input('sortNumber') num: number;
  private toggleSort: boolean = false;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      let parentNode = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
      let children = parentNode.children;

      if (this.data && this.key) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortArray();
      }
      this.toggleSort = !this.toggleSort;
    })
  }

  sortArray(): Array<any> {
    let tempArray: Array<any> = this.data;
    tempArray.sort((a, b) => {
      let aKey = a[this.key];
      let str1: string = a[this.key].toLowerCase();
      let str2: string = b[this.key].toLowerCase();
      let num1: number = parseInt(a[this.num]);
      let num2: number = parseInt(b[this.num]);
      if (this.toggleSort) {
        if (str1 < str2) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (str1 > str2) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (num1 < num2) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (num1 > num2) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      else {
        if (str1 > str2) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (str1 < str2) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (num1 > num2) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (num1 < num2) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    });
    return tempArray;
  }

}
```

I tried to add parseInt() , tried without parseInt() but no progress at all, BTW if possible I don't want to seperate my directive just use one directive for multiple scenarios.

My HTML:

```
 <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
    <th sortColumn [sortKey]="'name'" [data]="vms">VM Name</th>
    <th sortColumn [sortKey]="'ipAddress'" [data]="vms">IP Address</th>   
    <th sortColumn [sortNumber]="'diskSize'" [data]="vms">Disk Size</th>   
    <th sortColumn [sortNumber]="'cpu'" [data]="vms">CPU</th>   
    <th sortColumn [sortNumber]="'ram'" [data]="vms">Ram</th>   
    <th sortColumn [sortKey]="'imageUrl'" [data]="vms">Image Url</th>
    <th sortColumn [sortKey]="'role'" [data]="vms">Role</th>
    <th sortColumn [sortKey]="'status'" [data]="vms">Status</th>
    <th sortColumn [sortKey]="'project'" [data]="vms">Project Name</th>
    <th sortColumn [sortKey]="'hypervisor'" [data]="vms">Hypervisor Name</th>  
  </thead>
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data to work with?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I am getting data from db, btw strings works fine

Comment: I understand that. I'll just need some sample json data to work with. Can you please post some of it here? :)

Comment: javascript default provides reverse method which works for both string and numbers. Can we use that to simplify things? hit console.log([1,2].reverse())

Comment: @SiddAjmera `[{"id":35,"name":"kubernetes99","ipAddress":"192.168.1.1","diskSize":1221,"cpu":12121,"ram":121,"imageUrl":"www.google.com","role":"Kubemaster","status":"Pending","project":"Avengers","hypervisor":"Docker","gateway":"192.168.0.1","netmask":24}`

Comment: @SiddharthPal to be precise how and where I need to implement reverse()

Comment: In your sortArray method can you just return ```this.data.reverse()``` and remove everything else. As I see you are always toggling it.

Comment: @SiddharthPal tried , not worked unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding seperate method:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sortColumn]'
})
export class SortDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any;
  @Input('sortKey') key: any;
  @Input('sortNumber') num: number;
  private toggleSort: boolean = false;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      let parentNode = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
      let children = parentNode.children;

      if (this.data && this.key) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortArray();
      }

      if (this.data && this.num) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortNums()
      }
      this.toggleSort = !this.toggleSort;
    })
  }

  sortArray(): Array<any> {
    let tempArray: Array<any> = this.data;
    tempArray.sort((a, b) => {
      let aKey = a[this.key];
      let str1: string = a[this.key].toLowerCase();
      let str2: string = b[this.key].toLowerCase();
      if (this.toggleSort) {
        if (str1 < str2) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (str1 > str2) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      else {
        if (str1 > str2) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (str1 < str2) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    });
    return tempArray;
  }

  sortNums(): Array<any> {
    let tempArray: Array<any> = this.data;
    tempArray.sort((a, b) => {
      let num1: number = parseInt(a[this.num]);
      let num2: number = parseInt(b[this.num]);
      if (this.toggleSort) {
        if (num1 < num2) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (num1 > num2) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      else {
        if (num1 > num2) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (num1 < num2) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    });
    return tempArray;
  }


}
```